# Appending text, written in variable, below current line using sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I can append text below current line, using the `sed` editor:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "some text"|sed "a\bar"
some text
bar
```

But when I try to append text from variable below current line, using `sed`, I am not able to do it:

```
$ foo=bar
$ echo "some text"|sed "a\$foo"
some text
$foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the dollar sign using a backslash (`\`):

```
$ echo "some text"|sed "a\\$foo"
some text
bar
```

Works fine here.